# Por que não integrar o SOPT com o Ideone (ou outra ferramenta do tipo)?

Tags: novo-recurso

É muito comum ver pessoas ilustrarem código em perguntas ou respostas com um link para o [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) ou outra ferramenta do tipo. Eu acho uma prática bacana porque ajuda no entendimento de um problema ou de sua solução.

Mas ela também tem aquele velho problema do link externo: se um dia a ferramenta usada estiver fora do ar, a postagem fica inútil a não ser que o autor tenha tomado o cuidado de *repetir* o código lá e aqui. Além disso, copiar o código duas vezes é tedioso. Se eu descobri um pequeno bug depois de ter postado tenho que lembrar de corrigir em dois lugares...

Enfim, a vantagem de ter código executado na página existe, tanto que há o botão de inserir snippet para HTML+CSS+Javascript. Além disso, será que uma integração assim não estimularia os membros da comunidade a postarem perguntas com exemplos mínimos? :)

Sendo assim, existiria a possibilidade do SOPT implementar uma integração com uma ferramenta dessas, para que o código pudesse ser digitado e executado diretamente aqui (sendo automaticamente duplicado na ferramenta quando necessário)? Além da vantagem para os usuários, o SO não precisaria se preocupar com segurança do código (porque isso provavelmente já é feito pela ferramenta externa).

Perguntas relacionadas:

- [Por que não temos um compilador PHP?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5641/por-que-n%c3%a3o-temos-um-compilador-php)
- [Uma forma de compartilhar projetos de IDEs](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5369/uma-forma-de-compartilhar-projetos-de-ides)

Comment: Por isso estou colocando em dois desses sites e no GitHub (que não executa). É importante que além de colocar externamente tem que colocar no site também, senão fica "resposta somente link". Eu acho que aumentaria a postagem de MVCEs, mas não muito porque as pessoas não postam porque não tem isso, é porque não querem ou não sabem fazer um MCVE. É raríssimo alguém usar esse recurso em pergunta. O Stack Snippet o pessoal usa mais erado do que certo. O que chama de integração? Se for integrar com essas existentes, resolve um ou dois problemas deles, e piora pelo fato de ter em um só lugar.

Comment: @bigown A integração seria ter um botão do tipo do Snippet que permitisse digitar o código aqui no SOPT mesmo (ou importar uma URL). Então, quando o post fosse visualizado, o código (armazenado aqui, na pergunta mesmo) e o resultado (executado lá na ferramenta externa - se ela estiver online) fossem apresentados.

Comment: Realmente, ter em um lugar externo só causa um potencial problema. Mas por isso o código seria mantido aqui também. Só a execução seria externa. Se um dia a ferramenta deixar de existir, uma integração alternativa pode ser implementada.

Comment: Muita gente pode usar errado, igual o caso do snippet, uma excelente ferramenta mas muito mal utilizada: [Quando devo usar o snippet e quando não devo?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5752/quando-devo-usar-o-snippet-e-quando-n%C3%A3o-devo), no entanto seria um upgrade e tanto, talvez se fizessem

Comment: @FelipePaetzold Verdade. Mas muita gente pode usar certo.

Comment: @LuizVieira com certeza, talvez fosse o caso de liberar o recurso após o usuário atingir certa reputação, já deixaria o caso de mau uso menor

Comment: @FelipePaetzold Pode ser. Vale inclusive para o problema com o snippet. Mas acho que são discussões distintas (implementação do recurso vs educação no seu uso). Algo que, se pararmos pra pensar, vale pra qualquer coisa aqui no SOPT. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira exatamente, mesmo um recurso como o código em destaque é mal usado, eu já usei ele pra sublinhar palavras que não eram código, felizmente parei com isso rsrs, mas realmente tudo é questão de aprendizado e a comunidade do SO-pt é bem forte quanto a isso, mesmo eu achando difícil que um recurso como esse seja aprovado, fiz uma pergunta sobre colocar tabelas no editor de texto, e por lá descobri que já foi pedido e declinado :/

Answer (score 4):

Não tenho certeza, mas creio que "não vai estimular", na verdade acredito que vai causar mais problemas, isso porque geralmente as pessoas não seguem o [*MCVE*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ou seja os códigos nem funcionariam, se no *Stack Snippet* já temos este tipo de problema (o pessoal usa para marcação, mas os códigos simplesmente não executam) imagine a quantidade de códigos não funcionais em serviços de terceiros (com algo como IDEONE), iria desestimular quem responde (creio eu).

### Sobre o IDEONE

O IDEONE é gratuito para uso próprio/usuário final, mas para uso de terceiros o caminho seria a [*API*](https://ideone.com/sphere-engine) (acesse http://sphere-engine.com/pricing), o Sphere Engine é pago.

Independente de ser um serviço IDEONE ou outro, talvez não comportasse os sites da rede como *SOpt*, *SOru*, *SOes*, *SOja* e até outros como *codegolf* e mesmo que comportasse teria provavelmente um gasto elevado.

### Conclusão

- Creio que qualquer serviço além do *Ideone* não permita integração de forma gratuita sem ter um limite, o que não é viável a rede
- O outro problema é que mesmo que eles decidissem integrar e arcar com os custos ainda sim pode ter certeza que a maior parte dos usuário iriam usar de maneira totalmente errada o que provavelmente tornaria tudo muito inútil, ou seja seria um gasto alto para pouco proveito
- **Agora o mais importante**, mesmo que os demais itens citados acima não fossem empecilhos, ainda haveria a situação do *tempo de desenvolvimento, implementação* e *testes*, o que necessitaria de profissionais para desenvolver e ajustar para um bom funcionamento nos sites da rede que são necessários, ou seja seria mais custos a empresa.

De qualquer forma creio que somente alguém da *Staff* pode confirmar alguma motivação para não ter tal funcionalidade.

Comment: Bons pontos levantados. Valeu pela opinião. :)